# How to use do.call to add elements to a ggplot object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Objection

I would like to use `do.call` to combine a list of layers `e` with a main plot `g`.
My intention is to use `annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(x))` objects (where `x` is an independent `ggplot` object) 
to overlay a main plot with.

- `e`: objects of class `LayerInstance`/`Layer`/`ggproto`
- `g`: object of class `gg`/`ggplot`

### Simplified problem

This simplified example uses a list `e` of calls to `geom_*` functions:

```
library(ggplot2)
# data
d <- data.frame(a = 1:3, x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
# main plot
g <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y, label = a))
# plot elements
e <- list(geom_point(), geom_text())
```

### Undesired solution

To combine the plot `g` with all elements in `e`, I could use single elements (which works) as in:

```
g + e[[1]] + e[[2]]
```

But my intention is (for automation reasons) to use `do.call`.

### Problem

Using `do.call` with `+` and a list of `g` and `e`s fails:

```
do.call(`+`, c(list(g), e))
# Error in .Primitive("+")(list(data = list(a = 1:3, x = 1:3, y = 1:3),  : 
#   unused argument (<environment>)
```

### Question

How can I use `do.call`, the `+` method and my list of `g` and `e`s correctly?

Comment: why not do a for loop by type of layer: 
for(1:length(e[geom_point_layer_only])){
g <- g + geom_points(my_options)
}
for(1:length(e[geom_text_layer_only])){
g <- g + geom_text(my_options)
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's wrong with just `g + e` ?

Comment: most elegant solution, compared to the `do.call` (by GGamba) and `Reduce` (by LyzandeR) approach.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need `do.call` for this. `do.call` uses the list you provided to run it as arguments within the function. `+` only takes 2 arguments though. If you want to chain calls with `+`, `Reduce` would do the job with the same call.

```
Reduce(`+`, c(list(g), e))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
do.call(`+`, c(list(g), list(e)))
```

[image]